Techniques and tools for fine-tuning Navigation2 planners (Smac, MPPI) to reduce erratic behavior on curved paths
’m currently working on a navigation scenario using the Navigation2 stack (ROS 2) to guide an Ackermann-steered vehicle through a set of GPS-defined waypoints. I’ve experimented with several planners and controllers:
Planners Tried:

Smac Hybrid-A (SmacPlannerHybrid):* Provided better path adherence on
straight segments but becomes erratic in curves.



NavFn: Tends to
produce less curvy paths, but that aren’t well-suited for non-holonomic (Ackermann)
constraints and as a result the robot get stuck (motion control)


Tried withing SmacPlanner adjusting angle quantization
bins* and modify each parameter value one by one: Still facing issues in curved sections.
Controllers Tried:

MPPI Controller: Offers a lot of tunable parameters and can produce
decent paths, but on curves, it continuously re-optimizes, causing
the vehicle to oscillate or loop instead of committing to a stable
turn.

Regulated Pure Pursuit (RPP): Didn’t yield good results with large
Ackermann vehicles; too much overshoot and difficulty in maintaining
stable curved trajectories. Pure Pursuit does not adhere to the curve and keep moving the truck straight.


I’ve attempted various strategies:
Waypoint Distribution:

Sending the full list of waypoints at once via
navigate_through_poses.

Breaking the route into smaller chunks (e.g., sending only 3
waypoints at a time) to see if incremental navigation reduces
re-optimization loops.

Increasing or decreasing the density of waypoints along a curve,
trying to “guide” the planner more explicitly.


Tolerance Adjustments:
Increasing the positional and angular tolerances  (Goal and Progress Checker) so that the controller or planner considers the waypoint “reached” without requiring precise alignment.
Despite looser tolerances, the planner still often attempts to return or re-route around a curve, as if it’s trying to “perfect” its approach.
Parameter Tuning:
Adjusting cost weights, lookahead distances, velocity limits, resolution and curvature-related parameters in Smac and MPPI.
Trying different motion models (Dubin, Reeds-Shepp) and changing the turning radius parameters.
The result so far is that the planner behaves well on straight lines and gentle arcs, but on tighter curves, it keeps “arguing with itself” — re-planning mid-trajectory, expanding the arc, looping back to try again, or failing to proceed smoothly as a human being would drive.
Questions:

Are there recommended tools, logging strategies, or visualization approaches to systematically fine-tune parameters in Navigation2 (particularly SmacPlannerHybrid and MPPI controller) to ensure the planner commits more reliably to curved paths without continuous re-optimizations?

What common procedures do experienced users follow to identify the
root cause of erratic behavior on curves (e.g., analyzing costmaps,
adjusting acceleration/velocity profiles, or using simulation
speed-ups to test more parameters quickly)? It is a pain to kill simulation, readjust the values of a lot of parameters, trying different combinations, relauch the simulation...

How can I achieve more “driver-like” behavior, where the vehicle
simply follows the provided waypoints (even if not perfectly, can be a rough line connection between the GPS Waypoints),rather than constantly re-optimizing and backtracking?

Is there a "magic tool" for reoptimization of parameters and
retesting in a kind of Pass/Fail to select the appropriate
parameters to each scenario?


Currently The truck is losing the track to the path and keeps always recalculating and re-following a new path. It is never "good enough" for it.
Any insights, examples of parameter sets, or recommended workflows would be greatly appreciated.

It doesn't look like you're specifying the goal orientations in your path, that's why its doing the loop-de-loops. Smac Planners are feasible, so they consider the platform's current pose (including orientation) and the goal pose (including orientation). If you don't populate the orientation, it'll just be 0.0 deg heading and the planner will plan to that at the goal pose, feasibly. That's what you're seeing there. NavFn is not feasible, its just a point-to-point planner without considering orientations.
As an aside, I love that first image, I got a good chuckle out of that! I'm going to save that for later demonstration reference about why setting goal orientations is important :-)

Thanks for the suggestion! I do indeed provide different orientations for each waypoint. I’m using a script based on the Nav2 GPS navigation tutorial’s 'logged_waypoint_follower', where I drive the robot with a joystick and record various distinct waypoints (lat/long/yaw). Each yaw is correctly converted into a quaternion. I’ve tried replacing the yaw values with zero or using the original recorded values, but the Smac planner still continuously calculates optimization loops. Here’s an illustrative image: https://i.imgur.com/DtYQvQT.png and my configuration file: https://pastebin.com/DDy7Uydg.

Moreover, when I use the Nav2 graphical interface in Rviz2 (NavigateThroughPoses) and manually send about 10 waypoints at a similar distance (around 10 meters) to what my script does automatically, I get the same result: these trajectory re-optimization loops appear. To illustrate, here’s another image showing the problem: https://i.imgur.com/zHgDNFX.png. My current configuration file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/LfZHLXd0.  I also tried changing the resolution of the global and local costmaps, which only increased or decreased the frequency of the loops, without  fixi the issue.

I tried filtering waypoints to 50m spacing, which reduced frequent loop patterns but didn’t fix the underlying re-optimization issue. As shown here (https://i.imgur.com/USgX8Wv.png), the planner still constantly recalculates and regenerates paths.@Steve Macenski Do you have any suggestions on fine-tuning the planner/controller parameters (my config) or adjusting the Behavior Tree (add/remove certain behaviors) to minimize these loops and yield more stable navigation?

I have the same issue and I've checked that waypoints are specified with orientation. Giving more space (minimaly 0.2m in my case) between points solves the problem but it still persist on turns where points are placed closer to each other. That's why I swapped to NavFN

@SKJQ I tested with the real truck last week the SMAC planner generated too much curved and swerved trajectories from the goal poses for an Ackermann vehicle. It recalculates the path everytime to "optimize" it , even when not needed, of course there is some influence of Behavior Tree. I've also switched to the NAVFn which presented a more stable behavior as global planner and  MPPI for local planner, allowing the robot avoid a big obstacle successfully. I would say that SMAC planner is still not suitable for large Ackermann robots, since I tried hundred of different Params values combination.
